# Problem about setting custom domain for static web on Files Storage Azure

Tags: azure

Problem about setting custom domain for static web on Files Storage Azure.

I already added domain in config screen and set cname in domain but still didn't worked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wGeS.jpg)

Comment: If the reply has solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mapping a root domain, not subdomains. From [Configure a custom domain name for your Azure storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name),

> The mapping does only work for subdomains (e.g. www.contoso.com). If
>   you want to have your web endpoint available on the root domain (e.g.
>   contoso.com), then you have to [Add a custom domain to your Azure CDN
>   endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain).

In this case, you can try to use a subdomain like `sub.contoso.com` in your DNS provider. Otherwise, you need a CDN endpoint for that root domain. For more details, you can get from [this blog](https://wrightfully.com/azure-static-website-custom-domain-https).